# How do I writing a variable to an edit box in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

So I am simply trying to select a folder and write the path to a editbox in Matlab's GUI.

But somewhere in there I have completely messed things up.

According to everything I have seen this looks like it should work.

I included a chunk of the GUI creation in case the mistake is there somewhere.

I am very new to Matlab, so this is sort of a first attempt for me.

```
%######################################################################
%Main Figure
%######################################################################
    %Used to center figure on screen
    sz = [600 700]; %figure size
    screensize = get(0,'ScreenSize'); %get screen size
    xpos = ceil((screensize(3)-sz(2))/2); %x position
    ypos = ceil((screensize(4)-sz(1))/2); %Y position

h = figure('units','pixels',...
              'position',[xpos ypos sz(1) sz(2)],...
              'menubar','none',...
              'toolbar','none',...
              'name','VAST TOOL MOCKUP',...
              'resize','off',...
              'numbertitle','off');

%Menu Items
m = uimenu(h,'Label','File');
aboutm = uimenu(m,'Label','About','callback',@about);
docm = uimenu(m,'Label','Documentation','callback',@documentation);
% loadm = uimenu(m,'Label','Load Data','callback','load');
exitm = uimenu(m,'Label','Exit','callback',@exit);

rightcolumn = 310;
    leftcolumn = 70;
    labellength = 200;
    labelalign = 'center';
    labelvalign = 'Middle';

    pbtWorking = uicontrol('style','push',...
                            'units','pix',...
                            'position',[rightcolumn+200 600 30 30],...
                            'string','...',...
                            'fontweight','bold',...
                            'fontsize',11,...
                            'callback',@pbtWorking_CB);


    editWorking = uicontrol ('style','edit',...
                        'units','pix',...
                        'position',[rightcolumn 600 200 30],...
                        'string','',...
                        'fontweight','bold',...
                        'fontsize',11);
```

This is the part that is giving me the error.

Error using VAST_alpha>pbtWorking_CB (line 311)
Not enough input arguments.

Error while evaluating UIControl Callback

```
function pbtWorking_CB(hObject,eventdata,handles)
    WD_filepath = uigetdir('Select a Working Directory...')

    if WD_filepath ~=0
        set(handles.editWorking,'String',WD_filepath)
    else
        set(handles.editWorking,'String',' ')
    end
```

I have been trying to fix it for so long I can just tell its going to be a super simple fix that I have completely overlooked.

So thanks in advance!

Comment: Try replacing whatever comes after `'String'`, like `WD_filepath` in the `IF` part to cell with `cellstr(WD_filepath)`.

Comment: Hey Divakar, I am not super familiar with Stack Overflow so I didn't see your comment until I had altered my code for Benoit_11. Of course I didn't save versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty of modifying a bit your GUI and it works fine now. Here are the things I have changed:

1) Stored the GUI components in the handles structure of the figure, so that it's easier to retrieve/change/whatever. With this handles structure, it's very easy to share data between the callbacks of your GUI. I think the error is caused by Matlab not getting handles as input since they were never defined or something like that.

2) In the function pbtWorking_CB I changed the if/else statement for a strcmp, which is more intuitive in my opinion. Anyhow please try this and see if it works for you:

```
function TestGUIListBox

%Used to center figure on screen
sz = [600 700]; %figure size
screensize = get(0,'ScreenSize'); %get screen size
xpos = ceil((screensize(3)-sz(2))/2); %x position
ypos = ceil((screensize(4)-sz(1))/2); %Y position



%// Create the handles structure associated with the figure. Every handles is stored in it and is thus accessible with the right calls to guidata and such. Please see below.
    handles.figure = figure('units','pixels',...
    'position',[xpos ypos sz(1) sz(2)],...
    'menubar','none',...
    'toolbar','none',...
    'name','VAST TOOL MOCKUP',...
    'resize','off',...
    'numbertitle','off');

%Menu Items
m = uimenu(handles.figure,'Label','File');
aboutm = uimenu(m,'Label','About','callback',@about);
docm = uimenu(m,'Label','Documentation','callback',@documentation);
% loadm = uimenu(m,'Label','Load Data','callback','load');
exitm = uimenu(m,'Label','Exit','callback',@exit);

rightcolumn = 310;
leftcolumn = 70;
labellength = 200;
labelalign = 'center';
labelvalign = 'Middle';

%// Store GUI components in handles structure...
handles.pbtWorking = uicontrol('style','push',...
    'units','pix',...
    'position',[rightcolumn+200 600 30 30],...
    'string','...',...
    'fontweight','bold',...
    'fontsize',11,...
    'callback',@pbtWorking_CB);


handles.editWorking = uicontrol ('style','edit',...
    'units','pix',...
    'position',[rightcolumn 600 200 30],...
    'string','',...
    'fontweight','bold',...
    'fontsize',11);

%// Update structure...IMPORTANT
guidata(handles.figure, handles);

function pbtWorking_CB(hObject,handles)

handles=guidata(gcf); %// Retrieve handles structure to access the components...i.e. the edit box in this case

WD_filepath = uigetdir('Select a Working Directory...')


   %// Actually you could skip the if/else statement altogether since the edit box is filled with wathever WD_filepath is, even if it's empty.
if ~strcmp(WD_filepath,'')
    set(handles.editWorking,'String',WD_filepath)
else
    set(handles.editWorking,'String',' ')
end
```

Comment: I have made the changes, but an odd situation has occurred where only the first UI element will appear in the GUI.

Comment: Its totally me. I just copied pasted your code into a new script it works perfectly. I have obviously messed something up.

Comment: Maybe too many follow up comments, but I only put handles = figure not handles.figure = figure

Comment: Yep sure that should work as well; however if you had many figures created from your GUI that could create some issues; that's why I like to always assigne actual variables/handles to stuff create in GUIs. But if it works that's the important!